# Validate R1:C1 to R2:C2 notation in google sheets

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I need to validate range R1:C1-R2:C2 range

I tried with,

```
function isValid(rc) {
    if (rc)
        if (rc.trim() === "") return false;
    var isPattern = /^[0-9]+:[0-9]+-[0-9]+:[0-9]+$/.test(rc);
    if (!isPattern) return false;
    return ((rc));    
}
```

But the above code also takes 9:9-0:0 or 0:0-0:0

UPDATE:

How do I check whether the given range after a numeric validation at client side is correct in the server side. Because, at server side range may be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that there are some alphabetic characters, then numeric characters - this is how to match a field: `[a-z]+\d+`. It will match some characters, then some numbers. E.g. `a1`, `ASD34`. It won't match `12` or `sab` though.

If you put all together, you get this regex:

```
/^[a-z]+\d+:[a-z]+\d+\s*-\s*[a-z]+\d+:[a-z]+[0-9]+$/i
```

Explanation:

- `/../i` matches case insensitively, so it's enough to specify `[a-z]`, no need to type `[a-zA-Z]`
- this matches a field: `[a-z]+\d+`, like `R1` or `B12`. It won't match `12` or `AB`
- `\s*-\s*` tolerates spaces around the dash
- so we got: `field:field-field:field` and that's what you want.

You can play with [this](https://regex101.com/r/vNZNnz/2) regex demo.

Checking if the values are actually okay, it takes more than a regex. You'll have to split the code by the dash and the colons and compare the values.